# Chinese Postman Problem (CPP) is NP-Complete for mixed graphs: why?

Tags: graph-theory

My real question is: why the distinction between mixed and directed graphs in this case? Can I not convert the mixed graph into a digraph in polynomial time (by replacing each edge with two arcs) and solve CPP in polynomial time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because if you take an unoriented edge and replace it with two arcs, the problem changes -- now the postman must travel down *both* of your two new edges whereas in the original mixed graph he just had to go *either* back *or* forth along it.